# Creating HTML element inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox

I have to create multiple checkboxes and display them in html at a specific place in the page.

I have created a div

```
<div id="htmlDiv">
</div>
```

and then created checkboxes in javascript (Ihave to create them dynamically),

```
function createNewCheckboxt(name, id){
var checkbox = document.createElement('input'); 
checkbox.type= 'checkbox';
checkbox.name = name;
checkbox.id = id;
return checkbox;
}
```

but how can I place these checkboxes in DIV i.e. at specific place in html page ?

Thanks

Aiden

Comment: `document.getElementById('htmlDiv').appendChild(checkbox)`

Comment: What if I have to show label on right side of checkbox too ? e.g.                                            checkbox....Label                                                                                                     checkbox....Label

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the parent element, to which you wont to attach your element, then use the `appendChild()` method, for example:

```
var checkbox = createNewCheckboxt('name', 'id'); // method defined in the question     
var parent  = document.getElementById('htmlDiv');
parent.appendChild(checkbox);
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild